# Android sending http request as unicode not working

Tags: android, http, unicode, ascii

Hi I am working with android .I am looking to send some data to a server but the data must me send in UNICODE. I searched in google and found "HTTP.UTF_8" method. But still it recieved in server as ASCII values.How can I send UNICODE data to server.Here is my code

```
 String message = "<ENVELOPE>"
    +"<HEADER>"
    +"<VERSION>1</VERSION>"
+"<REQVERSION>1</REQVERSION>"
+"<TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>"
+"<TYPE>DATA</TYPE>"
+"<ID>TPGETCOMPANIES</ID>"
+"<SESSIONID>"+SessionID+"</SESSIONID>"
+"<TOKEN>"+String.valueOf(token)+"</TOKEN>"
+"</HEADER>"
+"<BODY>"
+"<DESC>"
+"<STATICVARIABLES>"
+"<SVINCLUDE>Connected</SVINCLUDE>"
+"</STATICVARIABLES>"
+"</DESC>"
+"</BODY>"
+"</ENVELOPE>";


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://dev1.tallyenterprise.com");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-16");
        httppost.setHeader("ID", "TPGETCOMPANIES");
        httppost.setHeader("SOURCE", "EA");
        httppost.setHeader("TARGET", "TNS");
        //Log.d("DEBUG", "HEADERS: " + httppost.getFirstHeader("Authorization: Bearer"));

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = null;
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(message,HTTP.UTF_8));   


        //  HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       //   HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();


            responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why you are using **HTTP.UTF, no need of do it in the question, add the code what your using exactly.

Comment: i Already did it. But thats the way i convert it into unicode.Thats why I added it in the question

Comment: i am not talking about the HTTP.UTF, why u are using "*" around it?

Comment: `charset=utf-16`. If you say so then use `HTTP.UTF_16` instead of HTTP.UTF_8. By the way: if somebody tells you to send data in unicode then ask immediately which charset. Android by default uses utf-8 which is a unicode charset too.